# parse an xml file without changing the encoding and preserving the file format

Tags: xml, vb.net, encoding

The original xml file is encoded with `UTF-8 without BOM`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<some_text>
    <ada/>
    <file/>
    <title><![CDATA[]]></title>
    <code/>
    <parathrhseis/>
</some_text>
```

I try to set text to `title` in this function:

```
Dim myXmlDocument As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
Dim node As XmlNode
Dim s As String

s = "name.xml"
If System.IO.File.Exists(s) = False Then
    Return False
End If

myXmlDocument.Load(s)
node = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement

Try
    For Each node In node.ChildNodes
        If node.Name = "title" Then
            node.FirstChild.InnerText = "text"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    myXmlDocument.Save(s)
Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in XmlParsing: " + e.Message)
        Return False
End Try

Return True
```

The text is written correctly but the encoding changes to `UTF-8 with BOM` and also it
adds spaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<some_text>
    <ada /> <- here
    <file /> <- here
    <title><![CDATA[text]]></title>
    <code /> <- here
    <parathrhseis /> <- here
</some_text>
```

How can i solve these problems

SOLUTION (with the help of Bradley Uffner)

```
Dim fileReader As String

Try
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("original.xml")

    fileReader = fileReader.Replace("<ada />", "<ada/>")
    fileReader = fileReader.Replace("<file />", "<file/>")
    fileReader = fileReader.Replace("<code />", "<code/>")
    fileReader = fileReader.Replace("<parathrhseis />", "<parathrhseis/>")

    File.WriteAllText("copy.xml", fileReader) <- File.WriteAllText automatically stores it without the BOM
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message)

    Return
End Try
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually isn't a problem parsing the file, it's a problem saving it.

See this post for how to save xml without a BOM.
[XDocument: saving XML to file without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942825/xdocument-saving-xml-to-file-without-bom)

The relevant code is:

```
Using writer = New XmlTextWriter(".\file.xml", New UTF8Encoding(False))
    doc.Save(writer)
End Using
```

Typically you can control the formatting of the document via the `.Settings` property of the XmlTextWriter, but I don't see a property to control the spacing of self closing elements.  You might have better luck post-processing the output before saving to the filesystem by saving it to a stream and manually removing any spaces before "/>".

Comment: That is what i am trying to do now. Remove the spaces manually. Using the `XmlTextWriter` solves the problem with encoding but it also changes the text `UTF-8` to `utf-8`!! I have to change this also.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are the formatting requirements so strict?