# VB.NET Save XMLdocument as UTF-8 with BOM

Tags: vb.net, encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have written a test application to modify a few hundred XMLs, basically I modify a few nodes and then save the XML again.

The input XML files are UTF-8-BOM but the output is UTF-8 (as viewed in Notepad++).

The code runs on a console application in VB.NET 4.7.2 and this is my basic code:

```
Dim myXML As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
Dim node As XmlNode
myXML.Load(file)

nodelist = myXML.SelectNodes("//root/row") 

For Each node In nodelist
'All my code goes here
Next

myXML.Save(file)
```

I tried things like:

`myXML.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", "")`

But that didn't work. I have been searching and it seems everyone has the exact oposite issue and checking in the MSDOC I can't see any reference to specify BOM or not:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldeclaration.encoding?view=netframework-4.7

The issue is that when the files are imported to the DB without BOM some characters show corruption so I really need the same encoding.

After so much reading I could try to rewrite my app using `StreamWriter` instead `XMLDocument` but if there is a workaround about that I would pretty much prefer it :). Thanks!

Comment: Do the input files show character corruption? Can you show the declaration of the input files, with the BOM designation?  Is the encoding of the field in the DB the same?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23201476/3439404) (seems opposite to your problem so use `New XmlTextWriter(file, New UTF8Encoding(True))`)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @JosefZ I used this strategy:

```
 Using writer = New XmlTextWriter(file, New UTF8Encoding(True))
            Dim xmlsettings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings
            xmlsettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = False
            xmlsettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
            xmlsettings = writer.Settings
            myXML.Save(writer)
        End Using
```