# Generating XML in UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to generate an XML message with "UTF-8" encoding only:

```
Dim doc As System.Xml.XmlDataDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDataDocument(ds)
Dim n1 As System.Xml.XmlNode = doc.FirstChild



Dim doc2 As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument
doc2.LoadXml(n1.FirstChild.OuterXml)



doc2.InsertBefore(doc2.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), doc2.FirstChild)
doc2.Save(outFile)
```

Each time the file is generated however, the encoding is listed as "UTF-8 Signature". I've tried to remove the first three characters from the message using something along the lines of:

```
def xmlbytes = outFile.toString().getBytes().flatten()
xmlbytes.remove(0)
xmlbytes.remove(0)
xmlbytes.remove(0)
```

Which has failed as well.

Is there a more efficient method for ensuring the encoding remains as "UTF-8" only?

I'm not using xDocument so I cannot apply the solution from the other thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XDocument: saving XML to file without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942825/xdocument-saving-xml-to-file-without-bom)

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of `XDocument` is confusing you - the solution detailed in [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942825/xdocument-saving-xml-to-file-without-bom) should still apply. But to be clear,

Instead of

```
doc2.Save(outFile)
```

try

```
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(outFile, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
    doc2.Save(writer);
}
```